# How to make Sphere Transparent using ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, opacity

This is the code I used
Edit: This is the full code to create this image

```
R[r_, s_] := {r, s, 0};
S[r_, s_] := {2 r/(r^2 + s^2 + 1), 2 s/(r^2 + s^2 + 1), (r^2 + s^2 - 1)/(r^2 + s^2 + 1)};
f[t_] = Tan[(Pi/2) * t];



Show[ParametricPlot3D[R[r, s], {r, -3, 3}, {s, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> 600, 
  Epilog -> Inset[Style[" 710178 ", FontSize -> 84, Red, Opacity[0.1]]]],
 ParametricPlot3D[S[f[r], f[s]], {r, -3, 3}, {s, -3, 3},PlotStyle -> Transparent]]
```

And this is my output
[image]

The reason I'm trying to make it transparent is because I have to plot curves on the sphere and currently when I do plot, I can't see the curves.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide all of the code to reproduce the image. The definitions for `R`, `S`, and `f` are missing.

Comment: My apologies, I was unaware that the full code was required, however I have added it. Just for further information, I tried to plot the sphere S first, instead of the plane R and that still made no difference

Comment: How about `Show[ParametricPlot3D[R[r, s], {r, -3, 3}, {s, -3, 3}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2], 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Style[" 710178 ", FontSize -> 84, Red, Opacity[0.1]]]], 
 ParametricPlot3D[S[f[r], f[s]], {r, -3, 3}, {s, -3, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1]]]
`

Comment: The circle just becomes a light orange when I change opacity. I also tried `PlotStyle-> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1]]`, but that didn't do anything

Comment: try  if `PlotStyle -> FaceForm[]` gives what you need.

Comment: `PlotStyle -> None`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a version problem. In MMA 12.3 I get:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[R[r, s], {r, -3, 3}, {s, -3, 3}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Style[" 710178 ", FontSize -> 84, Red, Opacity[0.1]]]], 
 ParametricPlot3D[S[f[r], f[s]], {r, -3, 3}, {s, -3, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Transparent]]
```

[image]

**Update**

To make the plane translucent, you could write:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[R[r, s], {r, -3, 3}, {s, -3, 3}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3], 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Style[" 710178 ", FontSize -> 84, Red, Opacity[0.1]]]], 
 ParametricPlot3D[S[f[r], f[s]], {r, -3, 3}, {s, -3, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Transparent]]
```

[image]

Comment: Output in Mathematica 13.0 appears to be the same as that from 12.3 you show.